# Will uninstalling the Byobu Window Manager break my GUI?

Tags: package-management, window-manager, byobu

I'm currently uninstalling redundant applications from my Ubuntu 10.10 system and I came across the Byobu Window Manager under the 'Provided by Canonical' section. Does this play any sort of critical role in window management, or is it simply a redundant application that's been included to facilitate some niche operation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu) is a user-friendly wrapper around GNU Screen, which is a terminal multiplexer.

Unless you're a command line junkie or sysadmin you likely don't need it; you can remove it without it affecting your GUI.

Comment: There are some things I don't like about it despite being a command-line junkie...primarily that it breaks Ctl-A to go to beginning of line.  Also, if I have to go to the trouble of configuring a CLI wrapper, I may as well just make my own desktop widget that contains the same info.

Comment: aking1012, what you're saying there though sounds much more like an issue with screen itself, since Ctrl-A is its escape character. You should probably try switching that to a different escape, which can be done in the configuration file (and I'm pretty sure Byobu doesn't override it).